# Is this a bug in javascript? The method push of Array object

Tags: javascript

This is the example code.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var i, arr = [], result = [];

    arr.push(1);
    arr.push(2);
    arr.push(3);

    for ( i = 0; i < 20; i++ ) {
        arr.push(5);
        arr.push(6);

        result.push(arr);
        arr.length = 3;
    }

    console.log(result);
}
```

Output:

```
 Array[20] 

 0: Array[3] 

 1: Array[3] 

 2: Array[3]

 etc...
```

Comment: What were you expecting?

Comment: And where is your "bug"?

Comment: I guess the result of `arr.length = 3;` is causing the "bug"

Comment: You may think you are pushing an array into `result`, but you are really pushing a reference to an array.  So every element of `result` is a reference to the same array.  When you modify `arr`, you are modifying every element of `result`.

Answer (score 4):

Your array of arrays contains a **reference** to an array which you set the length of to 3. This is exactly the result you should get. [Link to ECMA 5.1.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/)

Answer (score 2):

```
window.onload = function() {
    //create ONE array arr and one array result
    var i, arr = [], result = [];

    //fill array with three values
    arr.push(1);
    arr.push(2);
    arr.push(3);


    for ( i = 0; i < 20; i++ ) {
        //fill array with two more values
        arr.push(5);
        arr.push(6);

        //add a reference to arr to result
        result.push(arr);

        //change the length of arr to 3 => delete the last two items
        arr.length = 3;
    }
    //----> this repeats twenty times. you add two items to arr, add a reference to arr 
    //to result and delete the two items again. but the references that are stored in     
    // result will always point to one and the same array arr. 

    //and that's what you get in the end: and array filled with 20 references to another 
    //array with three items in it.
    console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: +1 though it would be better to _not_ write your whole answer as comments in a code block

Answer (score 0):

```
result.push(arr);
```

When you call the above, you haven't pushed the contents of arr onto result; you've pushed arr itself onto result.

The first time your loop runs, arr has 3 elements and you push 2 more onto it; arr now has 5 elements (1,2,3,5,6). You push arr onto result - arr still has 5 elements, and result has 1 element which is a reference to arr.

Now you set the length of arr to 3, so arr has 3 elements (1,2,3). result still has one element, and it's still a reference to arr.

Beyond that, I'm not sure what you were expecting nor where you think the bug is. If you still think there's an issue, you're going to have to explain more.